# Redshift Stored Procedure - [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "$1";

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

My Agenda is to store the counts of the 2 tables ( being passed in the parameter ) and then do some more operations upon comparing the both.

**PROBLEM -**

Stored Procedure throwing Error :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dev.gp_count_matching_20191204(actual_tablename character varying(256), bkp_tablename character varying(256))
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
actual_table_name varchar(256);
backup_table_name varchar(256);
actual_count_query varchar(1024);
actual_count int;
backup_count_query varchar(1024);
backup_count int;
BEGIN
call dev.gp_test_error_handling_tablename_format(actual_tablename);
call dev.gp_test_error_handling_tablename_format(bkp_tablename);

actual_count:=(select count(*) as counts from actual_tablename);
--raise info 'Actual Table Name - %, Actual Table Count - %',actual_tablename,actual_count;
end;
$$
```

This throws the following Error while creating the stored procedure-

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dev.gp_count_matching_20191204(actual_tablename character varying(256), bkp_tablename character varying(256))
 LANGUAGE pl...

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "$1";
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 0.99s
```

If I comment out the `actual_count:=(select count(*) as counts from actual_tablename);`
then the Stored Procedure gets created Successfully.

I guess it has something to do with me using the parameter ( since $1 points the first parameter ) in the query. 
Since I am pretty new with Stored procedure, I unable to figure out the exact problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name,
Previous -> actual_count:=(select count(*) into actual_count from actual_tablename);
post_change -> select count(*) into actual_count from actual_tablename;
Though the procedure gets created but the same error appears when i call the procedure.

Comment: You can't pass a table name as a parameter. You need dynamic SQL

Comment: hmm, interesting , Last time i checked redshift doesnt allow Dynamic Sql Queries.
@a_horse_with_no_name, then storing it in a variable like - actual_table_name:=actual_tablename; and then substituting this value this variable in that query doesnt help either.
So, my question is , Will changing the language from plpgsql help me here ?
If it will, then will there be any issue(compatibility) , if i use this stored procedure written in some other language in another stored procedure written in plpgsql .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `EXECUTE` when running dynamic SQL. In your example the query is in parentheses but nothing is making it execute. To execute the query into a variable you using the `INTO` syntax

```
sql := 'SELECT …'
EXECUTE sql_var INTO result_var;
```

Please see the example Stored Procedures in our GitHub repo "Amazon Redshift Utils". https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/tree/master/src/StoredProcedures

There are several examples that use dynamic SQL, such as https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/StoredProcedures/sp_split_table_by_range.sql

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the below-given syntax:

```
SELECT INTO Count count(*) from table_name;
```

By doing this you are inserting the value of `count(*)` into variable `Count`. It works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it